# Convert Array from JSON File into a Javascript Array does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

even though I read alot of related articles about this topic on stackoverflow,
I cant figure out what im doing wrong here.

So I have a json (peak.json) file with multiple objects and one array (audiopeakdata). It looks like this:

```
{"version": 2, "channels": 1, "data": [0.1, 0.3, 0,3 ... 0.1]}
```

Now I want to read the data-array from the json file and want to parse it into a an javascript array:

```
var array = [];
$.getJSON('peak.json', function(data) { 
    array = data.data;
}); 
console.log(array);
```

But the console log shows that the array is empty - how can that be?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The data works correctly with `JSON.parse`

Comment: check the network tab and share the exact data

Comment: It's because you're console logging outside the callback

Comment: Try `array.push(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becuase you are trying to return data from a `callback` which doesn't work. Use `async/await`:

```
async function getData() {
  var data = await $.getJSON('peak.json')
  var array = data.data;
  console.log(array);
}
getData();
```

Or move your `console.log` inside callback:

```
var array = [];
$.getJSON('peak.json', function(data) { 
  array = data.data;
  console.log(array);
});
```